# How to secure Nginx with python-certbot on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: http, nginx, dns, ssl-certificate, ubuntu-server

I'm struggling with the following problem. I have a droplet in the digitalocean.com service on which I have installed ubuntu 16.04 server. On this server I installed the Nginx HTTP server. For this server I would like to connect the domain purchased by Google Domains, which requires an SSL connection to the server. To get certificate I started this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04 I installed python-certbot-nginx and started configuring Nginx. When the certification for domains begins, there are errors related to the Google DNS:

```
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for placeholder.app
http-01 challenge for www.placeholder.app
Waiting for verification ...
Cleaning up challenges
Failed authorization procedure. www.placeholder.app (http-01): urn: ietf: params: acme: error: dns :: 
DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for www.placeholder.app

IMPORTANT NOTES:
- The following errors were reported by the server:

Domain: www.placeholder.app
Type: None
Detail: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for
www.placeholder.app
```

Is there any simple solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to download the SSL certificate online and then just include it in Nginx configuration file like so.

$ **sudo nano /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf**

Edit your configuration and make your server listen on port 443 with http2 instead.

```
listen       443 http2;
listen       [::]:443 http2;
server_name  localhost;
```

Then right under it, add the path to your SSL certificate keys.

```
ssl        on;
ssl_certificate         /etc/certificate/public/certificate.pem;
ssl_certificate_key     /etc/certificate/private/certificate.key;
```

Save and exit.

Now put your public key in here:

$ **sudo nano /etc/certificate/public/certificate.pem**

And your private key in here:

$ **sudo nano /etc/certificate/private/certificate.key**

You have now installed your SSL certificate. Please restart your nginx server for the changes to take effect.

$ **sudo systemctl restart nginx.service**

[Reference](https://hostup.org/blog/how-to-secure-your-nginx-server/)